# select_tag to choose which param to pass as true into the query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
  <%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'popularity', true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name = "nil", :id => "submit" %>
  <% end %
```

when selected it results in:

> www.example.com/users?popularity=true

However, because I have multiple order scopes, what I want to do is to create a select_tag with a dropdown, where the Use can choose between `popularity`, `photos_count` and `recent_activity` and
his **single** choice will be passed into the query string as such:

> example.com/users?popularity=true

or

> example.com/users?photos_count=true

or

> example.com/users?recent_activity=true

Comment: Well if you you want to *select* between options, rails has a tag for that too doesn't it?

Comment: can you be more specific please? i don't know how to use `options_for_select` with the above goal

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Read the rails guide on forms - try to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Just to clarify: you know that this can be solved with options_for_select? I have already tried to solve it and have already read all of that before your first comment...

Comment: @MageeWorld I found a solution using enum and options_for_select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not actually a :sort_type column in my user database. I am just using `enum` as a way of organizing the scopes so that one of them can be passed into the query string.

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>    
  <%= select_tag :sort_type, options_for_select(User.sort_types, :selected => params[:sort_type]), :include_blank => true %>  
<% end %>

class User
  enum sort_type: ["popularity", "number of photos"]
end
```

I then use the controller to set the scope based on the params[:sort_type] integer that was passed into the query string from the form.